# Not entirely clear on what this code does? (Includes Set, HashMap and .keySet())

Tags: java

So I've finished a program and have had help building it/worked with another person. I understand all of the program in terms of what each line of code does except one part. This is the code:

```
Set<String> set1 = firstWordGroup.getWordCountsMap().keySet();
         Map<String, Integer> stringIntegerMap1 = set1.stream().collect(HashMap::new,
    (hashMap, s) -> hashMap.put(s, s.length()), HashMap::putAll);

stringIntegerMap1.forEach((key,value) ->System.out.println(key + " : "+value));
```

Some background info:

- getWordCut is a method that looks like this:

  public HashMap getWordCountsMap() {

  ```
      HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

      for (String word : this.getWordArray()) {
          if (myHashMap.keySet().contains(word)) {
              myHashMap.put(word, myHashMap.get(word) + 1);
          } else {
              myHashMap.put(word, 1);
          }

      }

      return myHashMap;
  }
  ```
- firstWordGroup is a constructor that stores a string of words.

If anybody could explain exactly what this block of code does and how it does it then that would be helpful, thanks.

P.S: I'm not sure if supplying the whole program to reproduce the code is relevant so if you think it is, just leave a comment saying so and I will edit the question so you can reproduce the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<String> set1 = firstWordGroup.getWordCountsMap().keySet();
```

This line calles `getWordCountsMap` which returns a map from words to their count. It then ignores the count and just takes the words in a set. Note this could be achieved in a lot of much simpler ways.

```
Map<String, Integer> stringIntegerMap1 = set1.stream()
    .collect(HashMap::new, (hashMap, s) -> hashMap.put(s, s.length()), HashMap::putAll);
```

This converts the set of words to a stream and then collects the stream. The collector starts by creating a hash map then, for each word, adding a map from the to its length. If multiple maps are created (as is allowed in streams) then they are combined using `putAll`. Again there are much simpler and clearer ways to achieve this.

```
stringIntegerMap1.forEach((key,value) ->System.out.println(key + " : "+value));
```

This line iterates through all entries in the map and prints out the key and value.

All this code could have been achieved with:

```
Arrays.stream(getWordArray())
    .distinct().map(w -> w + ":" + w.length()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This command converts the words to a stream, removes duplicates, maps the words to the output string then prints them.

Answer (score 1):

**getWordsCountsMap()** returns a map where the key is a word and the value is how many times the word occurred in the array

```
Set<String> set1 = firstWordGroup.getWordCountsMap().keySet();
```

The **.keyset()** method returns just the keys of the map, so now you have a set of the words, but have lost the occurrence counts.

```
Map<String, Integer> stringIntegerMap1 =
    set1.stream()
        .collect(HashMap::new,
                (hashMap, s) -> hashMap.put(s, s.length()),
                 HashMap::putAll)
```

This is using Java8 streams to iterate through the set (words) originally put into a map and create a new hash map, where the key is the word (as it was before) and the value is the length of the word (whereas originally it was the word count).  A new hash map is created and populated and returned.

What I'm not understanding is the final HashMap::putAll() which would seem to take the hashmap just populated and re-add all entries (which really would be a no-op because the keys would be replaced).  Since I haven't whipped open my IDE to put in the code and test it (which, if you haven't yourself, would recommend, I'm just not interested enough to do so because it's not my problem!).

```
stringIntegerMap1.forEach((key,value) ->System.out.println(key + " : "+value));
```

In essence, this is a cleaner way to iterate through the entries in the map created, printing out the word and length for each.

After working through this and thinking about it, I have a feeling I'm doing your homework for you, the real way to figure this out is to break things down and debug through your IDE and seeing what each step of the way does.

Comment: I explained the `putAll` in my answer. Collectors are designed to allow separate execution threads to collect different elements and then combine them. The `putAll` is the method to combine the results together. The maps being combined will have different elements so putting all the elements from one into the other is effectively merging them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think we press the submit button at about the same time because both response kicked up together1  Thanks.

Comment: Yep I suspect we both saw each others answer and wondered :-)